# memcached Version 3.0.4 does not have REST xml available install failed

Tags: memcached, plesk

i follow a tutorial from plesk to install memcache(d), he say put this line:

## /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/pecl install memcached

But this work not and i get this error:
Package "memcached" Version "3.0.4" does not have REST xml available
install failed

What i can do? Have any a how to for noobs? :-)

Best regards, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce this error. I have successfully compiled module with

yum install plesk-php72-devel gcc make libmemcached-devel

/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/pecl install memcached

libmemcached directory [no] : **/usr**

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. A linux-men has installed for me the Modul. Then we can`t solve this problem here.